# Remapping memory from one kernel module to a DMA buffer in another module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, dma

I am working on a project where *module A* has a memory buffer that has DMA content and calls *module B*'s function to perform DMA operation. To simplfy it looks like below:

*Module A:*

```
void get_info()
{
    void *outBuffer = kmalloc(10);
    void *inBuffer = kmalloc(10);

    perform_dma(outBuffer);       // function from module B

    read_output(&inBuffer);      // function from module B
}
```

*Module B:*

```
void perform_dma(void *outBuffer)
{
    void *dma_buffer = dma_alloc_coherent()  // <-- allocate a new DMA buffer
    memcpy(dma_buffer, outBuffer, 10);

    do_dma();  // <-- after this is done, dma_buffer has the content module A needs.
}

void read_output(void **inBuffer)
{
    memcpy(*inBuffer, dma_buffer, 10);
}
```

I understand this might not be efficient but I can't change *module B* and can use only provided APIs. I am allowed to change *B*'s `perform_dma(void *outBuffer)` prototype to `perform_dma(void **outBuffer)` in best case. It works most of time but in a situation (due to all interrupts/queue events involved in the whole project) I won't be able to call `read_output()` explicitly and provide an `inBuffer` to read the content back but can only access `outBuffer` address after sending it to *B*.

Is there a way I can map `outBuffer` form module *A* to the `dma_buffer` allocated in module *B* to be able to read the output back from same `outBuffer`?

Comment: How restrictive are the changes you can make to module B. You mention you might be able to change the prototype, can you add a function?  Also, where is dma_buffer declared? You have it declared in perform_dma, but access it in read_output, which wouldn't be able to access it as you have it written.

Comment: I have figured out that dma_map_single()/dma_unmap_single() work in my case. There is no need to change function prototype at all. Just use dma_map_single(outBuffer...., DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL) inside perform_dma() to obtain a bus address and pass it to dma controller,  so after DMA is done  outBuffer would have the content returned from dma controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that dma_map_single()/dma_unmap_single() work in my case. There is no need to change function prototype at all. Just use dma_map_single(outBuffer...., DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL) inside perform_dma() to obtain a bus address and pass it to dma controller, so after DMA is done outBuffer would have the content returned from dma controller.